# Load view when button is clicked in Xcodes Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, storyboard

I just started to use Storyboard in Xcode. I have a starting view that has some buttons inside. Is there a way to load a special view when a button is clicked?

I only found this workaround:

```
-(IBAction)loadRegistration:(id)sender {
    // load registration controller
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    RegisterController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterController"];
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any code to load a new view. You just control-drag from the button to the controller you want to present, and choose the segue type. If the controller with the button is in a navigation controller you can choose push or modal, if it's not, then you want to choose modal.

Comment: I always used "push", which never worked. However, "modal" works as expected. Thx.

Comment: @dooonot, yes, push only works if the controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it seems ok. You can also connect the current View Controller to the one you want to present with a segue in the Interface Builder (ctrl + drag). When the button is tapped, you would call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identifier"];`. Of course, you set the id of the segue in the IB.
Even more simpler would be to connect the button with the new View Controller in IB (also ctrl+drag). This way you won't even need the IBAction.